# UseReducer change state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Im just making a simple app where the I get a data from api then display its title. On initial render, its working fine but whenever I try to change the value by giving an input(number), it doesnt work. can someone please help me point out whats wrong with my code? TIA
Heres the screenshot of my code.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q47ns.png 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d1FvV.png

```js
import React, {useReducer, useEffect} from "react"
import axios from "axios"

const initialState = {
    isLoading : true,
    isError : '',
    id: 1,
    fetchedData : {}    
}

const actionHandler = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type)
    {       
        case 'success' : 
            return {
                isLoading : false,
                isError : '',
                fetchedData: action.fetchedData
            }
        case 'error': 
            return {
                isLoading : false,
                isError : 'Something went wrong!',
                fetchedData: {}
            }
        case 'change' : 
            return {...initialState, id : action.value}
    }
}

function HooksUseReducerDataFetchingApp()
{
    const [data,action] = useReducer(actionHandler,initialState);
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${data.id}`)
            .then(response => {
                action({type:'success', fetchedData: response.data, error : 1000})                              
            })
            .catch(error => {               
                action({type:'error'})
            })
    }, [data])
    return(
        <>
            {data.isLoading ? 'Loading...' : console.log(data) }
            { data.isError ? data.isError : null }<br />
            <input 
                type="number"
                placeholder = "Enter a number"
                value = {data.id}
                onChange = { (e) => action({type: 'change', value: e.target.value }) }
            />
        </>
    )
}

export default HooksUseReducerDataFetchingApp
```

Comment: Please add the code snippet instead of an image to it

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `initialState.id` in you axios call. Instead you need to pass `data.id` as a `useEffect` dependency and pass it in your axios call.

You need use `state` value in your actionHandler to get the correct value:

```
const actionHandler = (state,action) => {
    switch(action.type)
    {       
        case 'success' : 
            return {
                ...state
                isLoading : false,
                isError : '',
                fetchedData: action.fetchedData
            }
        case 'error': 
            return {
                ...state,
                isLoading : false,
                isError : 'Something went wrong!',
                fetchedData: {}
            }
        case 'change' : 
            return {...state, id : action.value}
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using data.id on axios call but it says data.id is undefined

Comment: Have updated the code. There is a problem in `actionHandler` function. Please check.